# Prove the inequality on the solution of the wave equation.

Tags: integration, inequality, partial-differential-equations, estimation, wave-equation

Let the solution of the $d$-dimensional $(d = 1, 2, 3)$ wave equation Cauchy problem be $u_d(\vec{x}, t)$ with initial conditions $\phi(\vec{x}), \psi(\vec{x})$ non-zero at $|\vec{x}| \leq 1$ and zero at $|\vec{x}| > 1$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
(P):\begin{cases}
u_{tt} - a^2 \Delta x = 0,\\
u(\vec{x}, 0) = \begin{cases}
\phi(\vec{x}), & |x| \leq 1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},\\
u_t(\vec{x}, 0) = \begin{cases}
\psi(\vec{x}), & |x| \leq 1,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
$u_d(\vec{x}, t), (d = 1, 2, 3)$ is the solution of $(P)$. Prove that there exists a constant $C_d$ such that
\begin{equation}
|u_d(\vec{x}, t)| \leq C_d(t + 1)^{-\frac{d-1}{2}}, \vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^d, t \in \mathbb{R}.
\end{equation}
This is my PDE teacher assigned as a possible final exam topic, is about the solution of the maximum mode estimation, 1-D case proof is very simple, but the 2-D and 3-D case is beyond my ability, 3-D case I can get $|u(\vec{x}, t)| \leq C_3 t ^{-1}$, but the conclusion is still a part of the difference, 2-D case is unable to start, could you give me some hints or answers?

By the way, I found a material that uses **Sobolev space** in the proof, but we didn't study this, so please use **integrals and fundamental inequalities only** for the proof if possible, thanks!